# How to reduce unused CSS, laravel 10, vitejs

Tags: vue.js, vite, laravel-10

I'm using vite ,vue js, and laravel version 10. Now I trying to make my first app on this framework, and trying to optimize my code for google page speed. I solved almost every step, but i still have this proble:

[image]

Is that possible to fix that? I've looked for pure css plugins for vitejs, but no one worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package:
https://github.com/jowast/vite-plugin-purgecss

Installation:

```
npm install --save-dev @mojojoejo/vite-plugin-purgecss
```

For example, that's my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import pluginPurgeCss from "@mojojoejo/vite-plugin-purgecss";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    const isProduction = mode === 'development' ? false : true;
    return {
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: [
                    'resources/sass/app.scss',
                    'resources/js/app.js',
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
            isProduction ? pluginPurgeCss({
                content: [
                    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
                    './resources/js/**/*.js',
                ],
                defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
            }) : '',
        ],
        build: {
            sourcemap: true,
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: This works for me on Laravel 10 with Livewire 3